# get marker position from nested google maps marker array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, phonegap-build

I a function within an application that adds a marker to the map on button click, this marker also allows users to enter information in the form of editable elements as well as being able to delete the marker on request.

```
var markers = [];

counter = 0;

function addMarker(position) {
counter++;

    var bridgeIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("img/map_markers/warning_map_marker.png", null, null, null);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "Hello!!",
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: bridgeIcon,
        id: counter
    });

    markers.push(marker);

        //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
        var contentString = '<div class="marker-info-win">' +
            '<h3>Marker Information</h3>' +
            '<div class="warning-title" contenteditable="true" data-text="Warning Title"/></div>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' +
            '<div class="warning-additional-info" contenteditable="true" data-text="Warning Additional Information"></div>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' +
            '<br/><button id="deleteButton" name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove Marker" data-id="'+ counter +'">Remove Marker</button></div>';

        //Create an infoWindow
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        //add click event listener to marker which will open infoWindow          
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this); // click on marker opens info window 
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
        var button = document.getElementById('deleteButton');
        var id = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-id'));  
        button.onclick = function() {
            deleteMarker(id);
        };
    });
}

function deleteMarker(markerId) {
   for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].id === markerId) {

            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code creates the marker and pushes it to an array, the issue i am having is retrieving the markers from the array to use on a map on another page, i have tried to loop through the array to get the markers LatLng but it doesn't output to the page, neither am i receiving any errors?

```
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

The above code is the looping action that occurs on the page load and should load all the markers from the array based on their positions.

console.log(markers) returns the following

```
    [Lh]0: Lh
__e3_: Object
__gm: Object
anchorPoint: T
animating: false
animation: null
changed: function (a){a in e&&(delete this[Wc],d.j[Ze(this)]=this,Y0(d))}
clickable: true
closure_uid_180767458: 412
draggable: true
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
icon: Objectid: 1
internalPosition: lf
map: Zk
position: lf
title: "Hello!!"
visible: true
__proto__: c
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create another array with pure data and put all the information you need. So you will get something like:

```
var markersData = []
```

When you create a marker inside a loop add an index:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: googleMap,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    labelContent: "A",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
    labelClass: "labels",
    labelInBackground: false,
    index: i
});
markersData.push(marker);
```

Then inside your handler you can access the data by

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    var info = markersData[this.index];
    ...
});
```